# URL won't redirect to detailview pk Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, detailview

I have a simple project and made troubled fixing the redirection.
The url is not redirecting to my statistics_detail.html. whenever i click it just adds the pk on the link but won't redirects

here is my **url.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.StatisticsDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url('blist/', views.StatisticListView.as_view(), name='blist'),
    url('user_list', DisplayView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
    url('new_user', views.new_user, name='new_user'),
    url('push_user_tb', views.push_user_tb, name='push_user_tb'),
    url('push_user_prod', views.push_user_prod, name='push_user_prod'),
    url('st', views.display_stats_logs, name='st'),
    url('today', views.display_today, name='today'),
    url('balance', views.display_balance, name='balance'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class StatisticsDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'statistics_details'
    model = models.Statistics
    template_name = 'provision/statistics_detail
```

here is also **statistics_detail.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Statistics</p>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mac ID</th>
                <th>Hours</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        {% for clients in object_list %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ clients.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ clients.mac_add }}</td>
                <td>{{ clients.minutes_used|cut:".0" }}</td>
                <td>{{ clients.date }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{clients.id}}/">{{ clients.status }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
        It is {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see on the screenshot below. nothing happens if i click the clients.status which supposedly redirects to statistics_detail.html

Browser URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/prov/blist/
After Click the status it would only add http://127.0.0.1:8000/prov/blist/2146/ but doesn't work

[image]

Comment: still didn't work @BearBrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' clients.id %}">
```

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. i got those error after changing to {% url %}

Comment: This does not seem to be **full contents** of urls.py Also if this is app's urls.py file then please show how these urlpatterns are included into main urlpatterns.

Answer (score 3):

You need a leading slash: `<a href="/{{clients.id}}/">`

Even better, use the `{% url %}` tag rather than outputting the URL manually.

Comment: i did try changing to <td><a href="/{{clients.id}}/">{{ clients.status }}</a></td> but it looks i got a 404. new url was change to this http://127.0.0.1:8000/2146/ it was missing with prov/blist. i did try manually inputing the url with http://127.0.0.1:8000/prov/blist/<PK>/ it looks like the re_path could not still catch